# Use expand.grid in R to create all possible combinations of x factors in sets of y

Tags: r, dataframe, combinatorics

Is it possible to use `expand.grid()` in R to create all possible combinations of x factors in sets of y?

For example, I have 12 factors:

```
Factor1 = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),       #Fixed Attribute: 4 lvls
Factor2 = c("5", "6", "7", "8", "9"),  #Fixed Attribute: 5 lvls
Factor3 = c("10", "11", "12","13"),    #Fixed Attribute: 4 lvls
Factor4 = c("14", "15", "16"),         #Fixed Attribute: 4 lvls
Factor5 = c("17", "18", "19", "20", "21"),  #Variable Attribute: 5 lvls
Factor6 = c("22", "23"),                    #Variable Attribute: 2 lvls
Factor7 = c("24", "25", "26"),              #Variable Attribute: 3 lvls
Factor8 = c("27", "28", "29")               #Variable Attribute: 3 lvls
Factor9 = c("30", "31", "32", "33"),        #Variable Attribute: 4 lvls
Factor10= c("34", "35"),                    #Variable Attribute: 2 lvls
Factor11 = c("36", "37", "38"),             #Variable Attribute: 3 lvls
Factor12 = c("39", "40", "41")              #Variable Attribute: 3 lvls
```

I would like to always include the first 4 in `expand.grid()` (i.e. they are fixed) and cycle in the last 8 in all possible sets of 4, which equals 70 unique sets. Then append all resulting 70 data frames.

I could to this the brute force way by creating 70 different `expand.grid()` block of code, but is there a not too technical elegant way to do this?

For example the brute force way would be as follows:

```
expand.grid(Factor1, Factor2,Factor3,Factor4,Factor5,Factor6,Factor7,Factor8)
expand.grid(Factor1, Factor2,Factor3,Factor4,Factor5,Factor6,Factor7,Factor9)
expand.grid(Factor1, Factor2,Factor3,Factor4,Factor5,Factor6,Factor7,Factor10)
expand.grid(Factor1, Factor2,Factor3,Factor4,Factor5,Factor6,Factor7,Factor11)
expand.grid(Factor1, Factor2,Factor3,Factor4,Factor5,Factor6,Factor7,Factor12)
....etc...
```

So I would end up with 70 different data frames because there is 70 unique ways to select 4 factors from factors 4-12 (i.e. 70 ways to select 4 items from a list of 8)

Additionally, I the resulting data frame would probably be 1.5 million rows. Would this cause memory issues?

Thanks,

Comment: Could you share the expected output?

Comment: Hi @ChirayuChamoli, I've added an example of how I would do it by brute force. Please let me know if this is enough clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you right, this should do what you want:

```
l <- list(
    Factor1 = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),       #Fixed Attribute: 4 lvls
    Factor2 = c("5", "6", "7", "8", "9"),  #Fixed Attribute: 5 lvls
    Factor3 = c("10", "11", "12","13"),    #Fixed Attribute: 4 lvls
    Factor4 = c("14", "15", "16"),         #Fixed Attribute: 4 lvls
    Factor5 = c("17", "18", "19", "20", "21"),  #Variable Attribute: 5 lvls
    Factor6 = c("22", "23"),                    #Variable Attribute: 2 lvls
    Factor7 = c("24", "25", "26"),              #Variable Attribute: 3 lvls
    Factor8 = c("27", "28", "29"),               #Variable Attribute: 3 lvls,
    Factor9 = c("30", "31", "32", "33"),        #Variable Attribute: 4 lvls
    Factor10= c("34", "35"),                    #Variable Attribute: 2 lvls
    Factor11 = c("36", "37", "38"),             #Variable Attribute: 3 lvls
    Factor12 = c("39", "40", "41")              #Variable Attribute: 3 lvls
)



# Get the names of the other 8
others <- names(l)[-c(1:4)]
# Get names of the 4 fixed ones
fixed <- names(l)[1:4]

# Get all combinations of 4 of names of the others
combos <- combn(others, 4)

# Get the list of 70 expand grid outputs of combinations (fixed, combo_of_4)
out <- apply(combos, 2, function(x) expand.grid(l[c(fixed,x)]))
```

Comment: Thanks @FridolinLinder. How do I then coerce these lists into a data frame?

Comment: Not sure what you want to do with it, you can coerce them into one dataframe, but note that the columns in each frame mean something different.

Comment: If you want to do it this should work: `f <- function(x) {
    colnames(x) <- rep("a", 8)
    return(x)
};
b <- lapply(out, c_colnames);
df <- do.call(rbind, b)`

Comment: Can't edit my comment: It should be `b <- lapply(out, f)`